# How many strong simple addition mathagrams of degree one are there in a given base?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Define a simple addition mathagram in base $k$ as a triplet of strings of letters $\{s_1, s_2, s_3\}$, each letter representing a digit in base $k$, and each string thus representing an integer $\{n_1, n_2, n_3\}$, expressed in base $k$, such that there is some assignment of digits to letters making this a valid addition.  For example,
$$ SEND + MORE = MONEY $$ in base ten has at least the solution $9567+1085 = 10652$, that is, $ S\to 9, E\to 5 \cdots Y\to 2$.

For the purposes of this question, we will use the term "**mathagram**" to mean a simple addition mathagram.

We impose two additional conditions to call such a triplet a mathagram:

- No two non-identical letters may map to the same digit.
- The starting letter of each string must map to a digit other than zero.

When posing mathagram problems it is traditional to use letters that form words for each string, but for this question that is not required or even a consideration.

Define the **degree** of a of a mathagram to be the maximal number of appearances of any letter in either of the addends.   Thus the mathagram
$$ USE + LESS = SONNY $$ is of degree $2$ because of the two $S$ letters in the second addend.  (The letter multiplicities in the third string is moot for deciding the degree of the mathagram.)

Two mathagrams $\{s_1, s_2, s_3\}$ and $\{t_1, t_2, t_3\}$ are considered to be **equivalent** if

- $\{t_1, t_2, t_3\}$ is $\{s_2, s_1, s_3\}$, that is, they are the same triplets except the two addends are swapped (thus $MORE + SEND = MONEY$ is equivalent to $SEND + MORE = MONEY$); or
- there is a one to one mapping of the letters appearing in $\{t_1, t_2, t_3\}$ 
  to the letters appearing in $\{s_1, s_2, s_3\}$ such that when this map is applied to $\{t_1, t_2, t_3\}$ the result is $\{s_1, s_2, s_3\}$ (thus 
  $ABCD + EFGB = EFCBH$ is equivalent to $SEND + MORE = MONEY$); or
- they are both equivalent to some third mathagram (thus 
  $EFGB + ABCD = EFCBH$ is equivalent to $SEND + MORE = MONEY$).

This question asks about counting non-equivalent mathagrams; the purist might re-word the question as asking for the number of equivalence classes.

Finally, a mathagram is **strong** if and only if the "solution" (the mapping of letters to numbers, forming a correct addition statement) is unique.  For example, 
$ USE + LESS = SONNY $ is weak (is not strong) because it has two solutions:
$$814 +9411 = 10225 \\ 715 + 9511 = 10226 $$ On the other hand, $SEND+MORE=MONEY$ is strong, since its solution is unique.

This question concerns how many strong mathagrams exist in a given base $k$.  Since you can always form an infinite sequence of mathagrams from any mathegram just by repeating the strings, padding with zero's where necessary, for example, $$SENDOSEND + MOREOMORE = MONEYMONEY$$
we restrict our attention to mathagrams of degree $1$. Thus my principle  question is:

**How many non-equivalent strong degree-$1$ mathagrams exist in base $10$?**

In base $2$, there are only $3$ strong mathagrams (and no weak ones) of degree $1$: 
$$A+A=AB \\ AB + A = AA \\ AB + AB = ABB $$.

In base $3$ there appear to be $40$ strong mathagrams (and about 8 weak ones) of degree $1$.  Here, one must be careful not to over-count.  For instance, these two mathagrams are equivalent, by swapping addends and then doing a syclic letter replacement:
$$
ABC + BCA = BCBA \\ ABC + CAB = ABAC
$$

I will give at least "like" credit for answers for any base higher than $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have computed both the total number and the number of uniquely solvable problems for bases $2$ through $9$. (Sorry, at present I can't compute the answer for base $10$ in a reasonable amount of time.)

I have submitted these sequences to the OEIS (where I am planning to make the code available):

https://oeis.org/draft/A277496

https://oeis.org/draft/A277497

$$\begin{array}{ccc} 
\text{Base} & \text{# solvable} & \text{# uniquely solvable} \\
2 & 3 & 3 \\
3 & 49 & 43 \\
4 & 1020 & 909 \\
5 & 28666 & 25264 \\
6 & 1099824 & 946088 \\
7 & 57520786 & 49916876 \\
8 & 3882860433 & 3402999604 \\
9 & 331811494082 & 295506405205 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure the count for base 3 is only 40, but I could be wrong.  can you list the 43?

Comment: @MarkFischler See https://oeis.org/A277496/a277496.txt

Comment: @MarkFischler Have you looked at the list yet? Do you notice any mistake?